# Delete database table with column of datatype Image

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I got a table with these columns:

- PdfManuals:
- Id (PK, int, not null)
- Name (nvarchar(150), not null)
- ManufacturerId (int, not null)
- ClientId (nvarchar(50), not null)
- LanguageId (int, not null)
- ImageSize (nvarchar(50), not null)
- PdfName (nvarchar(150), not null)
- Image (image, null)
- Pdf (image, null)

And another table: PdfManuals_Manufacturers

1. Id (PK, int, not null)
2. Name (nvarchar(150), not null)
3. ClientId (nvarchar(50), not null)
4. LanguageId (int, not null)

And trying to perform this action:

```
public ActionResult DeleteManufacturer(int id)
    {
        var manufacturer = _db.PdfManuals_Manufacturers.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
        var pdfManuals = _db.PdfManuals.Where(x => x.ManufacturerId == id).ToList();

        if (manufacturer != null)
        {
            _db.PdfManuals_Manufacturers.DeleteOnSubmit(manufacturer);
            _db.PdfManuals.DeleteAllOnSubmit(pdfManuals);
        }
        _db.SubmitChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Manufacturers");
    }
```

But i get this error:

```
The data types image and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the equal to operator.
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC, and LINQ-To-SQL
I don't understand why, maybe you guys can help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by LINQ: it checks for the real change of the value (not always possibile as you can see...).

You can avoid this check with the clause UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never:

```
[Column(Storage="_myColumn", DbType="VarBinary", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public string myColumn
{
...
}
```

in the LINQ mapping of the column